# Realtime collaboration in Python

Tags: python, django, qt, collaboration

Is there any known way to do realtime collaboration stuff (like Google Docs) in Python (not thru the browser)? I'm working on a program, and would like to add said feature to it.
Thanks

Comment: I actually just created a client library in Java to do just that.

Comment: You can try [Dweet](http://dweet.io/), which is a service that stores JSON data in key values pairs.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: That looks like it would be pretty nice, but as far as I can see, it's only through the browser. Is there a way that you know of, so I could integrate it into the Python file (or at least the bits I need)

Comment: @Selcuk: Sounds good, I'll edit my post to ask "how", instead of "what". Thanks

Comment: I've started looking into Jabber (aka XMPP) for keeping track of this kind of information.

Web Sockets are new and up and coming and provide a lot of real time data.

Comment: @Meorge You can simulate browser entry with `urllib` requests.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "not thru the browser"?

Comment: I want this to be in a standalone program with its own icon and everything, not running inside a browser window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Dweet](http://dweet.io), which is a service that stores JSON data in key values pairs. You can use one of the client libraries listed on their website or you could simply make a request like so:

```
urllib.urlopen('https://dweet.io/dweet/for/my-thing-name?dweet=awesome')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm currently using Dweepy (a Dweet framework for Python) to do it, but so far it seems to work well. I'll repost if anything goes wrong, but thanks for the help :D

Comment: I'm currently making a Java client library, be sure to check it out [here](https://github.com/mbrahimi/Jibberish), or show it to your friends that know Java.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- I'm having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202708/issues-with-http-client-badstatusline this problem, now, with it. Would you know what the issue is?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really used Dweet enough to tell you.