# Issues with http.client.BadStatusLine: ''

Tags: python, http, pyqt, python-3.4

I have a program that uses Dweepy (a Python module for using the dweet.io service) and it can't run the stream function (listen_for_dweets_from) for some reason.

Code:

```
    collabIncomingThread = threading.Thread(None, self.listenForCollabCommands, daemon=True)
    collabIncomingThread.start()

    def listenForCollabCommands(self):
        print("Getting dweets...")
        for dweet in dweepy.listen_for_dweets_from('reggie-next-codes-' + shareid):
            print(dweet)
            contentcourse = dweet['content']
            code = contentcourse['code']
            #sender = contentcourse['player']
            print("IN: " + code)
            #if sender != myname:
            mainWindow.HandleCollaborationLang(str(code))
```

When this runs, it eventually prints out this stuff:
http://pastebin.com/MJdRriyH (the paste is infinite, I couldn't format it all for SO)

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the Threading stuff, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know?

Comment: I have experienced similar issues when connecting to the remote host failed due to broken SSH tunneling. Thus, the error is actually at the other end of the pipe. Though not sure if this applies to your situation.

Comment: Not that this is related to your issue, but if the `mainWindow.HandleCollaborationLang` method does anything with the PyQt GUI (which from the name, it sounds like it probably does) then your code is not thread safe. (Py)Qt forbids access to any GUI objects from threads that are not the Main Thread. I point this out because once you fix your current issue, you are likely to see random application crashes (segfaults) if you are breaking the Qt threading rules.

Comment: `HandleCollaborationLang()` is a simple function, to go to `CollaborationLang()`, which looks like this: http://pastebin.com/xZcCmGpU
So no, it doesn't do anything to the GUI, at least not directly (I think)